# How to % encode comma , in query params with Boost.URL

Tags: c++, boost, urlencode, boost-url

#### Intro

In my program I have a Google Places API client and to build `URL` I use `Boost.URL` library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/url/src.hpp>
#include <boost/url/encode.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>

...

boost::urls::url endpoint("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json");
auto params = endpoint.params();
params.append({"key", "PLACE_API_KEY" });
params.append({"input", "Tower" });
params.append({"radius", "500" });

auto location = std::make_pair(51.507351, -0.127758);
std::string locationString = std::to_string(location.first) + "," + std::to_string(location.secod);
params.append({"location", locationString});

std::cout << endpoint.encoded_target().substr() << '\n';
```

#### Problem

Unfortunately due to the URL RFC specification, it doesn't encode `,` (comma) symbol [because it's reserved](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109117/usage-of-comma-in-url-encoded-or-not-encoded)

So the code above print:

> `/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=PLACE_API_KEY&input=Tower&radius=500&location=51.507351,-0.127758`

If I replace `,` with `%2C` in `locationString` variable, the output will be:

> `/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=PLACE_API_KEY&input=Tower&radius=500&location=51.507351%252C-0.127758`

because `%` was encoded to `%25`

#### Question

Is there a way to percent-encode `,` in a query param value with `Boost.URL` API?

Comment: Downvoters, any comments?

Comment: I love this question. It's very real-life and the answer is not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly analyse, the RFC requires the comma to be preserved as-given.

It follows that you can *give* it as "%2C".

I figured out by reversing the path:

```
urls::url ep("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
             "json?key=PLACE_API_KEY&input=Tower&radius=500&location=51.507351%2C-0.127758");
for (auto [k, v, h] : ep.params())
    std::cout << k << " -> " << v << " (" << std::boolalpha << h << ")" << std::endl;
for (auto [k, v, h] : ep.encoded_params())
    std::cout << k << " -> " << v << " (" << std::boolalpha << h << ")" << std::endl;
```

Which prints

```
key -> PLACE_API_KEY (true)
input -> Tower (true)
radius -> 500 (true)
location -> 51.507351,-0.127758 (true)
key -> PLACE_API_KEY (true)
input -> Tower (true)
radius -> 500 (true)
location -> 51.507351%2C-0.127758 (true)
```

It follows, that appending to `encoded_params` should work:

```
urls::param_pct_view p("location", "51.507351%2C-0.127758");
endpoint.encoded_params().append(p);
```

And indeed it does:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/fErYnxMd1)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/url/src.hpp>
#include <boost/url/encode.hpp>
namespace urls = boost::urls;

int main() {
    urls::url endpoint("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json");

    auto params = endpoint.params();
    params.append({"key", "PLACE_API_KEY"});
    params.append({"input", "Tower" });
    params.append({"radius", "500" });

    urls::param_pct_view p("location", "51.507351%2C-0.127758");
    endpoint.encoded_params().append(p);

    std::cout << endpoint << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=PLACE_API_KEY&input=Tower&radius=500&location=51.507351%2C-0.127758
```

Comment: Awesome troubleshooting! Thanks a lot! I just found out that `"51.507351%2C-0.127758"` can be replaced with `boost::urls::encode("51.507351,-0.127758", boost::urls::unreserved_chars)`

Comment: That deserves to be its own answer